# How can i change my product page infinite scroll down

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to design my product page as a infinite scroll down.

Comment: Do you have using any Extension?

Comment: yes am using    https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/strategery-infinitescroll.html

Comment: its working but, but next level image not displayed

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7KPQo.png

Comment: is any possible ??

Comment: this is my result

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/RfB1dVE.png

Answer (score 1):

Do you get an errors in your browser console log?

The ajax call could be failing for some reason.

Comment: how can i solve his error

Comment: If you are using google chrome, press F12 to open element inspector and switch to the console tab. Load the webpage and scroll down and see if any errors appear

Without an error message it's a bit difficult to diagnose

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lvu4clX.png

Comment: There's no relevant console logs then, only a missing image.

Is there anything in your exception.log or system.log

Comment: Could you explain briefly.